# What does the word 'operator' mean in here?

Tags: idioms, american-english, idiom-meaning, literature

What does the word 'operators' mean in here? Does it actually mean technical operator or is it an idiom of some sort?

> I noticed a  connection  between  the  barn-burning  section  of The
> Moon  and the Bonfires  and  William Faulkner's The Hamlet before I
> discovered  that  this  was  the  final  novel  that  Pavese
> trans­lated;  Faulkner's  backwater  know-nothings  and **operators**  are
> an  American  counterpoint  to  the  have-nots  of  the
> impover­ished,  rural Italian  setting in Moon.

This is from Mark Rudman's introduction for Cesare Pavese's novel. I know Faulkner's The Hamlet has a social theme of some sort in it, but I can't find the connection between the word 'operator' with 'know-nothings', 'have-nots', and 'impoverished'.

Comment: Probably refers to the power players of the area at the time...Snopes and his kin.

Comment: You might read it as "manipulators".

Comment: From above comments, Merriam-Webster has Operator "2a: MOUNTEBANK, FRAUD
b: a shrewd and skillful person who knows how to circumvent restrictions or difficulties" https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/operator

Comment: Also, know-nothing may not mean exactly an idiot: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Know_Nothing

Comment: Like *a smooth operator*, I'd call an operator a big shot, or slick, but not necessarily bad or fraudulent.

Answer (score 1):

***operator***

The actual meaning of the  word in this sense (as used by [Mark Rudman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_Rudman))  *is difficult to find in Lexico and Cambridge.*

However, [YourDictionary](https://www.yourdictionary.com/operator) has

> An operator is defined as someone who is shrewd or manages difficulties easily. An example of an operator is a person who is an aggressive stock trader. An example of an operator is a man who can get a woman's phone number at a bar.

And, we do have *business operator* and  *political operator* in common usage.

> Facebook’s chief, once uninterested, has transformed himself into an active ***political operator*** in the Trump era

[WSJ](https://www.wsj.com/articles/how-mark-zuckerberg-learned-politics-11602853200)

[LawInsider](https://www.lawinsider.com/dictionary/business-operator) says...

> a **business operator** as defined in the Freedom of Business Activity Act of 2 July 2004,

And I also find...

> Leader, Manager, Operator--Which are you?

[Forbes](https://www.forbes.com/sites/erikaandersen/2013/02/17/leader-manager-operator-which-are-you/?sh=7b0196316095)

---

> What does the word mean in (sic) here?

I believe that in this case  it is a usage of a modern meaning that refers to shady deal makers and local politicians of of the 1850s. As far as I know, the word was not commonly used  at that period of time to describe corruption. There were other words. To confuse things even more, Faulkner was writing about fictional  events which had supposedly occurred a century before.

Any Faulkner reader will tell you that it no doubt refers to the nefarious actions of the Snopes family and their hangerson. They were an inherently corrupt lot, and often overly-appreciative of their own business acuity.

Comment: The reference to "know-nothings" is confusing...there was a resurrection of the Whig party in the 50s, but...